# Debugging a remote Java application with Eclipse as the server (Socket listen)

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a remote Java application from Eclipse, with Eclipse acting as the Server as opposed acting as a Client to the remote application. I launch the remote application with the following JVM options where 'server=n' will cause the remote application to connect back to Eclipse (Socket Listen) instead of Eclipse connecting to the remote app (Socket Attach).

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=n,address=8000
```

Finally, I configure Eclipse to listen on a port and then launch the remote app. The app connects to Eclipse and my breakpoints are hit. However, when I launch a second instance of the remote app with the above JVM options, the app fails with the following error indicating it was unable to connect to Eclipse.

```
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Is there a known issue in Eclipses' remote debugging that limits only one remote app to connect to it at a given time?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: From my experience, this apply to all java applications in debug mode (not just eclipse). It's not a client limitation. But i don't know that part the vm monitor would need different. (maybe a different debug agent?)

Answer (score 1):

To debug a second instance of the application, you'd have to start the second instance with a different port address (other than 8000) and reference that new port number when you start the debug session.

Comment: Dean, that would be the case if the debugger was a client to the debugee. Java provides another debugging method in which the debugee is the client and the debugger is the server. The debugger is expected to listen on a port before the debugee is launched. I wanted the debugger to listen on one fixed port and for all the debugged applications to connected back to the debuggers on that same port. Unfortunately, this does not work because I experimentally found that the debugger accepts only one connection at a time in this mode.

Comment: That is true (I somehow missed the 'with Eclipse acting as the Server' portion of your question). AFAIK in order to accomplish this, multiple instances of eclipse must be started, once for each port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an option in the Run Configurations->Remote Java Application.

[image]